# bash: compare between two files to append columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix

I have *two* files. 
The *first* file is like this:

```
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111111
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111112
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111113
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111114
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111115
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111116
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111117
name_service1|||S_SUCCESS||1111111118
```

And the *second* file is like this:

```
name_service1,20160705,0900
name_service2,20160705,0800
```

I need do a compare between the two files by the *name_service* field, and when the fields are the same add the date and the hour; something like:

```
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111111
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111112
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111113
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111114
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111115
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111116
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111117
name_service1|20160705|0900|S_SUCCESS||1111111118
```

The first file is large, so using a `while read` line and doing a `grep` for each line of the first file takes a long time.  The second file only has 5 or 6 lines.

Is there another way to do it?

Regards

Comment: assuming you can convert file2 to use `|` fld seps, `man join`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash`, `join`, `tr`, and `sed`:

```
join -t '|' -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7 -a 1 file1 <(tr ',' '|' < file2) | \
sed 's/|$//'
```

The same, but without *bash*isms:

```
tr ',' '|' < file2 | \
join -t '|' -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7 -a 1 file1 - | \
sed 's/|$//'
```